ORA-06530: Reference to uninitialized composite when using schema-level type
I created a record and a table of records on the db schema the following way :
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE WS_RESPONSE AS OBJECT (
valeur  VARCHAR2(1000 CHAR)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE WS_RESPONSE_TABLE AS TABLE OF WS_RESPONSE;

However, when I am trying to fill it with values in a stored procedure I get an error telling me it isn't initialized.
My local variable is declared the following way :
v_res            WS_RESPONSE_TABLE := WS_RESPONSE_TABLE();

P_KEYS in my case has the following value : 'results{}.attributes.stn_label:results{}.attributes.adr_number'
It is used to dynamically use different APIs. v_json has the answer of the interrogated API. I had tried the extraction part of the code and it gives the correct values.
This is how I am trying to fill it's values :
for i in 0..10
loop
    v_res.extend;
    for j in 0..REGEXP_COUNT(P_KEYS, ':')
    loop
        v_key := REGEXP_SUBSTR(P_KEYS, '[^:]+', 1, j+1);
        v_data := apex_json.get_varchar2(p_path => REPLACE(v_key, '{}', '[%d]'), p_values => v_json, p0 => i);
        IF j = 0 THEN
            v_res(v_res.last).valeur := v_data;
        ELSE
            v_res(v_res.last).valeur := v_res(v_res.last).valeur || ' ' || v_data;
        END IF;
    end loop;
end loop;

The procedure will raise an error at it's first value assignation. I tried different ways but no matter what I try it does not work. I already tried extending it by 10 rows before the loops and also different way to point to a record.
Example :
v_res(v_res.count).valeur := v_data;
v_res(i+1).valeur := v_data;

Can anyone help me out with this?

Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: a complete PL/SQL block including sample data for P_KEYS so we can run your statements and replicate the error; an English (not code) explanation of the problem you are trying to solve; and the expected output. At the moment, we have to try to reverse engineer your code to work out what it is trying to do (you appear to be trying to manually parse a JSON string using regular expressions - which is probably a bad idea) which makes it difficult to help you as we don't know what data you have, what you are trying to do or what is correct.

Why are you using an object with a single property? Why not use CREATE TYPE WS_RESPONSE_TABLE AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(1000 CHAR); and not use the object?

@MT0 I just updated the post.

You have a nested-table collection that contains NULL values and is not initialised. This is because v_res.extend; does not create a WS_RESPONSE instance in the collection; it just extends the collection so that there is space for another value and that position in the collection is initially set to NULL. You need to also create the objects within the collection.
DECLARE
  p_keys VARCHAR2(1000) := 'results{}.attributes.stn_label:results{}.attributes.adr_number';
  v_res  WS_RESPONSE_TABLE := WS_RESPONSE_TABLE();
  v_key  VARCHAR2(200);
  v_data CLOB;
  v_json CLOB := EMPTY_CLOB();
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 0..10 LOOP
    v_res.EXTEND;
    FOR j IN 0..REGEXP_COUNT(P_KEYS, ':') LOOP
      v_key := REGEXP_SUBSTR(P_KEYS, '[^:]+', 1, j+1);
      v_data := apex_json.get_varchar2(
                  p_path => REPLACE(v_key, '{}', '[%d]'),
                  p_values => v_json,
                  p0 => i
                );
      IF j = 0 THEN
        v_res(v_res.COUNT) := WS_RESPONSE(v_data);
      ELSE
        v_res(v_res.COUNT).valeur := v_res(v_res.last).valeur || ' ' || v_data;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END;
/

fiddle
